# how to parse JSON string in mingw-w64 g++ on Windows 10?

Tags: json, g++, mingw-w64

I am writing C++ using mingw-w64 g++ on windows with VS Code.

I need to be able to parse some JSON string.

mingw doesn't seem to have any built-in JSON support.

What is the way to set up JSON support in mingw-w64 on windows 10?

Comment: I tried https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp. It didn't work for me. Likely it is for Visual C++ not for MinGw G++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few libraries for handling JSON from C/C++ that you can use.

To name a few that I have been able to compile with MinGW-w64:

## JSON-C

Description    : JSON-C implements a reference counting object model that allows you to easily construct JSON objects in C, output them as JSON formatted strings and parse JSON formatted strings back into the C representation of JSON objects.

https://github.com/json-c/json-c

## libjansson

Description    : Jansson is a C library for encoding, decoding and manipulating
JSON data.

http://www.digip.org/jansson/

## libjson-glib

Description    : JSON-GLib is a library providing serialization and deserialization support for the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format described by RFC 4627.
Website URL    : http://live.gnome.org/JsonGlib

## json-parser

Description    : Very low footprint JSON parser written in portable ANSI C

https://github.com/udp/json-parser

## jsonh

Description    : json parser for C and C++

https://github.com/sheredom/json.h

## jsmn

Description    : jsmn (pronounced like "jasmine") is a minimalistic JSON parser
in C. It can be easily integrated into the resource-limited projects or embedded systems.

http://zserge.com/jsmn.html

## tiny-json

Description    : tiny-json is a versatile and easy to use json parser in C suitable for embedded systems. It is fast, robust and portable. It is not only a tokenizer. You can get data in string format or get the primitives values in C type
variables without performance loss.

https://github.com/rafagafe/tiny-json

## ujson4c

Description    : A more user friendly layer for decoding JSON in C/C++ based on
the ultra fast UltraJSON library

https://github.com/esnme/ujson4c/

## cajun-jsonapi

Description    : CAJUN is a C++ API for the JSON data interchange format with an emphasis on an intuitive, concise interface. The library provides JSON types and operations that mimic standard C++ as closely as possible in concept and design.

https://github.com/cajun-jsonapi/cajun-jsonapi

## frozen

Description    : JSON parser and generator for C/C++ with scanf/printf like interface. Targeting embedded systems.
Website URL    : https://github.com/cesanta/frozen

## jq

Description    : jq is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

## js0n

Description    : Flexible Zero-Footprint JSON Parser in C

https://github.com/quartzjer/js0n

## libfastjson

Description    : a fast json library for C

https://github.com/rsyslog/libfastjson

## libxo

Description    : The libxo library allows an application to generate text, XML,
JSON, and HTML output using a common set of function calls. The application decides at run time which output style should be produced.

https://github.com/Juniper/libxo

## microjson

Description    : Tiny JSON parser in C that uses only fixed-extent storage.

http://www.catb.org/esr/microjson/

## minijsonreader

Description    : A DOM-less JSON parser that can parse a JSON object without allocating a single byte of memory

https://github.com/giacomodrago/minijson_reader

## minijsonwriter

Description    : A simple, little-overhead, allocation-free, and extensible C++
JSON writer, directly wrapping a std::ostream

https://github.com/giacomodrago/minijson_writer

## pdjson

Description    : A public domain JSON parser focused on correctness, ANSI C99 compliance, full Unicode (UTF-8) support, minimal memory footprint, and a simple API. As a streaming API, arbitrary large JSON could be processed with a small amount of memory (the size of the largest string in the JSON). It seems most C JSON libraries suck in some significant way: broken string support (what if the string contains \u0000?), broken/missing Unicode support, or crappy software license (GPL or "do no evil"). This library intends to avoid these flaws.

https://github.com/skeeto/pdjson

## picojson

Description    : a header-file-only, JSON parser serializer in C++

https://github.com/kazuho/picojson

## sajson

Description    : Lightweight, extremely high-performance JSON parser for C++11

https://github.com/chadaustin/sajson

## smalljsonparser

Description    : This is a simple, one-file JSON parser in C. It is designed for highly resource-constrained systems. It uses no memory allocation, and can stream data, so that the whole file does not need to reside in memory.

https://github.com/DagAgren/SmallJSONParser

## univalue

Description    : C++ universal value object and JSON library

https://github.com/jgarzik/univalue

Comment: this is excellent. thank you. json-parser worked for me. I posted the how-to below.

Answer (score 1):

Following Brecht's list, I tried json-parser. The following is how I made it to work. Hope this will help folks not familiar with the process

Do this from Msys terminal which came with MinGw G++, becaue it has 'make' command.

```
   cd mycppbase
   git clone https://github.com/json-parser/json-parser.git

   cd json-parser
   export PATH=/c/msys64/mingw64/bin:$PATH
   ./configure
   make

   three files are important
   json.h
   libjsonparser.a
   libjsonparser.so

   cd myexampledir/
   g++ myjson.cpp -o myjson \
    -I "/c/.../mycppbase/json-parser" \
    -L "/c/.../mycppbase/json-parser" \
    -l:libjsonparser.a
```

UPDATE: 2022/11/20

the previous example is to link a static executable.

To link dynamically, we need to rename the .so file to .dll file. (see comments below)

The following is done in gitbash terminal and worked.

```
mv libjsonparser.so libjsonparser.dll
cd myexampledir/
g++ myjson.cpp -o myjson \
        -I "/c/.../mycppbase/json-parser" \
        -L "/c/.../mycppbase/json-parser" \
        -ljsonparser
```

Comment: Your question was tagged mingw-w64 so `libjsonparser.so` can't be right. For Windows targets it will be `libjsonparser.dll`. You can find my build recipe (where I fix this) at: https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/json-parser.winlib

Comment: You have a ground. The build only created .so and .a files, but there is no .dll file. Indeed I tried to link to the .so but failed. Therefore, I switched to link to .a file which worked, as seen in my example. I would try .dll if it were there.

Comment: The `sed` command in my build script modifies `Makefile` so it does generate `.dll` and `.dll.a` files. But maybe I should submit a pull request wuth a proper fix...

Comment: if you can fix the build, I will try again and update my example. Thank you

Comment: or you can run this command before the  `./configure` command: `sed -i.bak -e "s/\(SO_EXT\s*:=\s*\)so/\1dll/; s/\(libjsonparser\.\)so/\1dll/g; s/-Wl,-soname,\([^ ]*\)/-s -Wl,--out-implib,libjsonparser.dll.a/" Makefile.in`

Comment: @BrechtSanders following your suggestion, i just renamed the .so file to .dll. an it worked

Comment: Watch out with that because the linking `.dll.a` file may cause it to look for the original shared library file (with extension `.so`).